# How to monitor Ryzen Temperatures on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: monitor, temperature, monitoring

i found this post

https://linuxconfig.org/monitor-amd-ryzen-temperatures-in-linux-with-latest-kernel-modules

however the git repository they are using doesn't exist any more so i cannot try it.

hardware:

```
@SERVER:~$ sudo sensors-detect
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# Board: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG STRIX X370-F GAMING
# Kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 1800X Eight-Core Processor (23/1/1)

......

 Sorry, no sensors were detected.
Either your system has no sensors, or they are not supported, or
they are connected to an I2C or SMBus adapter that is not
supported. If you find out what chips are on your board, check
http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices for driver status.
```

Answer (score 8):

As of Linux kernel version *4.15* (which is the default for *Ubuntu 18.04.1*), both `it87` and `nct6775` modules are included in the release. You don't have to compile them yourself.

Here is what `it87` is capable right now – in this example on *AMD Ryzen 5 2600*:

```
$ sensors
it8792-isa-0a60
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.80 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in1:          +1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in2:          +1.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
+3.3V:        +1.67 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in4:          +1.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in5:          +1.17 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in6:          +2.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +1.67 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
Vbat:         +1.60 V  
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +30.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +34.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp3:        +34.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

If you need per core temperatures and/or better support for *AMD Zen 2* CPUs, they will be available in [4.21 kernel release](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/12/24/302) – hopefully by the end of *Q1'2019*. [More info on Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-F17-M30h-Linux-Temp-Changes).

UPDATE: 4.21 just became 5.0 with the [5.0-rc1 release](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/1/6/178)

Comment: How do I enable it87 with sensors-detect? my system currently only uses k10temp

Comment: @udiboy1209 Make sure `it87` module is loaded (check `lsmod`). If not, either load it using `modprobe` command or add it to your `/etc/modules-load.d` (_systemd_) or `/etc/modprobe.d` (_SysV_) to make it load automatically during boot.

Comment: just a note: even HWE kernel in 18.04.4 does not have "it87" sensors compiled even as module. :/