# How to load it87, to make lm sensors work with AMD Ryzen?

Tags: 19.10, amd-processor, lm-sensors

I want to get CPU temp/fun speed monitor for AMD Ryzen 3900x.

In this question I found, that I need to activate it87 module to work with  [How to monitor Ryzen Temperatures on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091671/how-to-monitor-ryzen-temperatures-on-ubuntu-18-04)

But then I try to do this, i get error:

```
$ sudo modprobe it87
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'it87': No such device
```

How to setup this? ubuntu version 19.10, linux 5.3, lsmod output:

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_usb_audio         241664  2
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
btrfs                1257472  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
zstd_compress         167936  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
ufs                    81920  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               110592  0
hfs                    61440  0
minix                  36864  0
ntfs                  106496  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   188416  0
xfs                  1273856  0
libcrc32c              16384  2 btrfs,xfs
cpuid                  16384  0
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
nvidia_uvm            913408  0
kvm                   643072  0
nvidia_drm             49152  8
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
nvidia_modeset       1122304  15 nvidia_drm
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia              19517440  744 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          49152  6
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_ctxfi             114688  4
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_ctxfi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
uvcvideo               98304  0
input_leds             16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
aesni_intel           372736  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 nvidia_drm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
videodev              208896  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
drm                   491520  11 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd                    86016  38 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_ctxfi,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ccp                    94208  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   126976  2 usbhid,hid_generic
i2c_piix4              28672  0
ahci                   40960  6
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0
realtek                20480  1
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
```

Comment: Have you tried the `k10temp` module instead?

Comment: Just tried, it enables, but looks like k10temp can't help with AMD Ryzen 3900x. `sensors-detect` shows "no sensors were detected"

Comment: Does `sensors` show anything with the module loaded?

Comment: @dobey PCI only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 'it87' is not supported anymore. I used [zenmonitor](https://github.com/ocerman/zenmonitor) instead

Comment: zenmonitor doesn't give fan speeds as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cer8s9/3900xgigabyte_x570_elite_working_well_on_linux/

(although I used this git repo: https://github.com/a1wong/it87 )

After building the module, load like this

```
sudo modprobe it87 ignore_resource_conflict=1 force_id=0x8622
```

note that I also have kernel boot parameter

```
acpi_enforce_resources=lax
```

I now see three fan speeds on my Aorus X570 board with Ryzen 3900X

Since that seems to work,
I have

```
/etc/modprobe.d/it87.conf
```

with contents

```
options it87 ignore_resource_conflict=1 force_id=0x8622
```

and add

```
it87
```

to `/etc/modules`