# How to install it87 kernel module for 18.04 (ryzen 2xxx support)

Tags: kernel, temperature, amd-processor, lm-sensors, amd-ryzen

I want to read the CPU temperature value of my ryzen 2600. [This askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107424/959725) answer says "just load `it87`". But how do I get `it87` installed? I'm running mainline `5.0.0-36-generic` so I expect the kernel module is available somewhere as 18.04.1 should have it by default and is packaged with kernel `4.15`.

The [github repo](https://github.com/groeck/it87) is a dead link for me. So I can't just compile it and load it by hand.

## update

My motherboard is a x470 chipset Asus ROG Strix x470-F gaming. It has a IT8665E.

I have `it87` installed in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/hwmon/it87.ko`.
When I load it using

```
sudo modprobe it87
```

Results:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'it87': No such device

`lm-sensors` results:

```
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8665
    (logical device 4 has address 0x290, could be sensors)
```

and forcing the issue results in:

```
sudo modprobe --verbose it87 force_id=0x8665
insmod /lib/modules/5.0.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/it87.ko force_id=0x8665
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'it87': No such device
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you by any chance see [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091671/how-to-monitor-ryzen-temperatures-on-ubuntu-18-04/1107424#comment1977862_1107424) on the answer you mentioned? If not, try it. If so, please [edit] that info into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I read that comment but yeah.... can't load something that isn't stored on my hdd.  I understand how to load the kernel module and how to make it load at boot, I want to install the kernel module (or save it on my hdd so I can manually load it). I can't compile the module also because of the dead git repo which everyone points to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your motherboard. You might [edit] the make and model into your post for those that have it to respond. The main chipset doesn't indicate what other chips may or may not be on the board. You might find [this information](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hwmon/it87.html) along with a visual inspection of the board in question useful in determining if your board even utilizes one of the supported chips. (I don't think so, but I won't claim to know for certain.)

Comment: @ElderGeek my apologies I misinterpreted some output from `modprobe`. `it87` is on my system.

Comment: [This suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192086/how-to-install-it87-kernel-module-for-18-04-ryzen-2xxx-support?noredirect=1#comment1995083_1192086) still stands.

Comment: @ElderGeek ofc. I updated the information. Seems like my ITE chip is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as [elder_geek](https://askubuntu.com/a/1192094/959725) noted the `IT8665E` chip is NOT supported by `it87`.

A solution however is [electrified's](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/new-linux-sensors-driver-for-crosshair-vii-and-other-boards-with-asus-wmi-sensors-interface/136381) [github repo](https://github.com/electrified/asus-wmi-sensors) which handles several Asus AMD motherboards.

Please note the requirement for the `ROG STRIX X470-F GAMING` that the bios should be a minimum version `5007`. (I have tested with the `5406` version).

You will need to install lm_sensors, DKMS, kernel sources, GCC, etc to compile the module.

The compile instructions for Ubuntu didn't work for me so here's what I did:

```
sudo make dkms
sudo make modules
sudo make install
sudo modprobe asus-wmi-sensors
```

And results from `sensors`:

```
asuswmisensors-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
CPU Core Voltage:         +1.20 V  
+12V Voltage:            +11.97 V  
+5V Voltage:              +4.93 V  
3VSB Voltage:             +3.33 V  
CPU Fan:                 1203 RPM
Chassis Fan 1:            734 RPM
Chassis Fan 2:           1196 RPM
Chassis Fan 3:            902 RPM
AIO Pump:                   0 RPM
Water Pump:                 0 RPM
CPU OPT:                    0 RPM
CPU Temperature:          +47.0°C  
Motherboard Temperature:  +35.0°C  
Chipset Temperature:       +0.0°C  
Tsensor 1 Temperature:     +0.0°C
```

Comment: Bravo! I'm glad you got it sorted. My wife has an Asus board that has similar issues, sadly it's not on the supported list and since it's a lightly used system it hasn't been high on my list of priorities. I may have to dig into it again now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the answer you want.

As of this moment it appears that the IT8665e chip is not supported by the it87 module. According to a support query by olysonek and a response by goeck found [here](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/134) and quoted below.

> re IT8665E: I had an out-of-tree driver supporting it on github, but marked it as private because I got harassed about taking it upstream which I didn't have the time for (much less anyone seriously reviewing it, or helping to kink out its bugs, or chip/board vendor support). There should be various clones of this driver (named it87) on github. There are no efforts I know of to take the code upstream.
>
> The IT8665E is often used in conjunction with IT8686E on the same board, and it is often accessed from an EC on the board. This causes interactions which I have not been able to sufficiently address. While that was somewhat acceptable for an out-of-tree driver, the resulting instabilities would affect lots of people if the code was upstreamed, which in my opinion is unacceptable. Anyone who wants the code upstream should discuss with ITE and board vendors to get the necessary support.

Answer (score 0):

When release upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, the module `it87` is no longer required. The module `coretemp will now take care of this.

To resolve this issue, simply delete every line mentioning `it87` in `/etc/modules`.

```bash
$ sudo nano /etc/modules
```

After this edit, issue the following command:

```bash
$ sudo /etc/init.d/kmod start
```

Because of this issue, my USB driver was not running
and I could not use my USB keyboard.

Luckily, I could still SSH to the machine from another machine to perform this edit.
If this is not possible, use a PS/2 keyboard or, as a last resort, a live boot disk to perform this edit.

After all this, I had to physically disconnect my USB keyboard and reconnect it for it to be properly detected.