# ubuntu 18.04, sensors-detect fails to find any sensors

Tags: 18.04, sensors, amd-ryzen

Specs:
motherboard: **ASUS ROG Strix B450-f**
cpu: **ryzen 2700x, 8core, 3.7Ghz**
Ubuntu 18.04, kernel **5.0.0-37-generic**

I run a `sudo sensors-detect` and I get "Sorry, no sensors were detected."

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no):
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8665
    (logical device 4 has address 0x290, could be sensors)
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
```

It looks like almost found a ITE sensor but apparently not.

Anybody run into this issue? are there kernel modules i might need to install for this motherboard to find the sensors?

Answer (score 2):

I have same situation. When I do: `sudo sensor-detect` - there is info that no sensors was found.

But when I do: `inxi -F` on the sensors line I have this:

```
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.4 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 46 C 
Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So this solution worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1192100/1024296

Installing this module per this comments instructions worked.