# Can't find my CPU temperature anywhere

Tags: cpu, temperature

I built a pc with the new(almost) Ryzen 7 5800x, and I tried multiple thing such as tooling like `sensors` or glances, to even look into `/sys/class/hwmon/` to find something but I really can't find them. Can you help me?

This is the output of `sensors`:

```
jc42-i2c-0-1a
Adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00
temp1:        +32.5°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +31.9°C  (low  = -60.1°C, high = +89.8°C)
                       (crit = +94.8°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +39.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +0.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)

jc42-i2c-0-18
Adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00
temp1:        +31.5°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
```

I'm missing most of my pc temperatures for some reason and I think even fans should show up

Comment: You've executed `sudo sensors-detect` in the terminal? If yes, did you add the result to `/etc/modules`?

Comment: Try looking around the thermal zones. Example: `grep . /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type` gave me: `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type:acpitz` and `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type:x86_pkg_temp`. Aghh, so now `grep . /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/type:x86_pkg_temp` gave me 34 degrees (well it gave me 34000 millidegrees).

Comment: @Smurfz87 I tried that command but I didn't add the results there, how can I do it?

Comment: @DougSmythies from `grep . /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type` I get `iwlwifi_1` which I think is the network card

Comment: sensors-detect is part of lm-sensors: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lm_sensors

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a driver for your motherboard to get those temperatures. For an MSI B450 board I used the appropriate NCT6775 driver. Try the "Additional Hardware feature" of gnome, it might detect it.

There has been asked as similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091671/how-to-monitor-ryzen-temperatures-on-ubuntu-18-04), it might help you.

Comment: I have a Asus ROG maximus impact vii and I couldn't find proper drivers, also I only get graphics card drivers in the "Additional Hardware" tab of the "Software and Updates"